# Issue with updating list in snake game

Tags: python, processing

So I've been programming a snake game using python mode for processing, but I have been having an issue with the list I have set up for keeping track of the body of the snake itself.

My current implementation uses a list of vectors to keep track of the location of each segment of the snake. I then loop through this list to display the squares for each segment. At the beginning of the game, the list only has 1 entry (the head), but upon eating a piece of food, I insert a new vector to the front of the list with the same value as the current head. I then update the list but looping through it and finally, I update the head by using a velocity vector.

```py
scl = 10
dim = 20

def setup():
    global s
    global f
    size(dim * scl, dim * scl)
    s = Snake()
    f = Food()

def draw():
    background(201)
    global s
    global f
    if s.eat(f):
        f.location()
    s.update()
    s.display()
    f.display()
    delay(50)

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = [PVector(0, 0)]
        self.v = PVector(1, 0)
        self.total = 1

    def update(self):
        for i in range(self.total - 1):
            self.body[self.total - 1 - i] = self.body[self.total - 2 - i]
        print("Position")
        print(self.body)                
        self.body[0].x += self.v.x * scl
        print(self.body)
        self.body[0].y += self.v.y * scl
        print(self.body)

    def display(self):
        fill(101) 
        for i in range(self.total):
            rect(self.body[i].x + 1, self.body[i].y + 1, scl - 2, scl - 2)

    def eat(self, p):
        tmp = self.body[:]
        dis = dist(self.body[0].x, self.body[0].y, p.pos.x, p.pos.y)
        if dis < 1:
            self.total += 1
            self.body.insert(0, tmp[0])
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I expect the output to be a list of differing vectors, each that draw a square next to the previous and next entries. Instead, after eating food, all the vectors are the same within the body list. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Why don’t you install [pudb](https://github.com/inducer/pudb) and debug your code to find out?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstood, how python's list handles it's values.

```
tmp = self.body[:]
```

makes shallow copy, not deep copy. And:

```
self.body[...] = self.body[...]
```

doesn't copy the value. It just passes the value from one place, to another. So when you move your values in `self.body` by one offset, the first and the second element will end pointing to the same value.

Try something like this:

```
def update(self):
    for i in range(self.total - 1):
        self.body[self.total - 1 - i] = self.body[self.total - 2 - i]
    print("Position")
    print(self.body)
    self.body[0] = PVector(self.body[0].x + self.v.x * scl, self.body[0].y + self.v.y * scl)
    print(self.body)
```

and in eat function:

```
self.body.insert(0, PVector(tmp[0].x, tmp[0].y))
```